# How to stroke a text in Camtasia Studio?

Tags: video-editing, camtasia

Is it possible to stroke a text in Camtasia Studio? And how? Put a text upon a text doesn't look enough. If not, is there a alternative video editor with this possibility (except Adobe After Effects and Sony Vegas)?

Comment: If you have a stroked font you want loaded on your machine. I would think you could use it in a callout (pick the font from the dropdown).  I know that is not exactly what you asked, but I don't believe Camtasia has that type of functionality built into it.  I could be mistaken though.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC Well, a stroked font may solve the problem, what I want to do is add a text border using font strokes. I'll try to find one... thanks.